# Android Phonegap: Notify javascript when an AsyncTask is finished

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-asynctask

in my app, when user click on a button in webview, a phonegap plugin will be called to trigger an asynctask to download file from internet. Now i want to send a signal back to javascript part when the asynctask is finished. But i don't know how to do it, because my plugin had already send something back before the asynctask is finished. Does anyone know how i can notify my javascript part without plugin in Phonegap?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I also asked this question in Phonegap Google Group, here is response of Simon Mac Donald. It works perfectly for me:

---

You can handle this situation by using the Plugin API quite easily. It 
is implemented in the core API items Connection and Battery. What you 
need to do is:

1) In your execute() method of your plugin save the callbackId you get.

2) Return a NO_RESULT plugin result and set keep callback id to true.

```
    PluginResult pluginResult = new  PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT); 
    pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true); 
    return pluginResult;
```

3) When you async java method finishes return another plugin result like this:

```
    PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, data); 
    result.setKeepCallback(false); 
    this.success(result, this.myCallbackId);
```

As I said, you can look at the code in GitHub to see how we are using this for Connection and Battery.

---

Comment: ...I did the same as mentioned above but it doesnt work all the time, sometimes I see values on HTML and sometimes a blank page.Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780372/asynctask-inside-execute-method-of-cordova-plugin

Comment: where is the github repo link?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solve problems like your.

1) Create and associate a JavascriptInterface to your WebView. A JavascriptInterface is simply a class inside which you can declare some Java method you want to use from JS.

```
public class JSInterface() {
    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void waitForProceed() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void canProceed() {
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

2) In your AsyncTask, at the end of `onPostExecute()` method, you have to call the `canProceed()` method to notify to JSInterface that it can exit from `waitForProceed()` method.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<.......> {
    private JSInterface jsi;
    ... // other class property

    public MyAsyncTask(JSInterface jsi) {
        ...
        //do what you want with other class property

        this.jsi = jsi;
    }

    @Override
    public ... doInBackground(...) {
        ...
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(...) {
        ...
        //do something

        jsi.canProceed();
    }
}
```

3) In your Activity you have to associate the JSInterface object to your WebView:

```
WebView mWebView;

...

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "JSIface");
```

4) Finally, in JS, you can call AsyncTask (I don't know how you call it, but I guess you use somthing like a JSInterface) and after call `waitForProceed()` method:

```
startAsyncTask(); //somehow
JSIface.waitForProceed();
```

I hope it solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed example:

Lets create some interface that should be called when `AsyncTask` will finish the stuff, a.e when `onPostExecute` called.

*In my case we fetch some `JSONArray` data*

**MyTaskListenerItf.java**

```
public interface GroupTaskListenerItf {
   public void onTaskDone(JSONArray groupArray);
}
```

---

The `AsyncTask` template of looks like:

**MyBuildTask.java**

```
public class MyBuildTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SomeData>{

    private MyTaskListenerItf mTl = null;

    public MyBuildTask(Context context,  MyTaskListenerItf tl) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;        
        this.mTl = tl;
    }

       @Override
       protected SomeData doInBackground(Void... params) {
          /* ... */
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(WmTransferItem transferItem) {
       // ...


        if(this.mTl != null){           
            JSONArray data  = new JSONArray("");            
            this.mTl.onTaskDone(data);
        }      

       // ..
     }
}
```

---

So now our `CordovaPlugin` class should look like:

**MyCordovaPlugin.java**

```
public class MyCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin implements GroupTaskListenerItf {

       // we need this callback when Task will finish
   private CallbackContext mMyCallbackContext = null; 

   @Override
   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
          if("runMe".equals(action)){
             final GroupTaskListenerItf gt = this;

              mMyCallbackContext = callbackContext;
             // pass our 'GroupTaskListenerItf' interface to async class    
              MyBuildTask task = new MyBuildTask(cordova.getActivity(), gt);
              task.execute();

        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult); 
          }
          else{
              this.cordova.getThreadPool().execute( new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                     // BTW, here you might run something else out of UI Thread
                    }
             });
          }
   }

/* ... */

 @Override
public void onTaskDone(JSONArray data) {

if (this.mGroupCallbackContext != null) {
        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, data);
        result.setKeepCallback(false);
        this.mMyCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
      }     
}
```

---

That's all.

Hope it will help to someone.