# Phonegap wait for asynchronus task to finish

Tags: android, multithreading, cordova, asynchronous

I hava a JS function which calls a native Java function. This native function sends a Bluetooth statement to a host. This host answers asynchronously, this answer is fetched by a Handler.

My question is, is it possible to send the result, which contains the answer, back to JS when the answer is actually there ?

I tried to send a second Callback, but this does not work properly, because the JS function does not wait until all results are there (as mentioned in this example : [Android Phonegap: Notify javascript when an AsyncTask is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751522/android-phonegap-notify-javascript-when-an-asynctask-is-finished)). It is finished before ...

Secondly i can't access this line of code (from the example), I think it is deprecated :

```
this.success(result, this.myCallbackId);
```

Hope you can help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I know, it might be not state of the Art or the performance might be really bad, but I found a workaround for myself :

First step is to send the requests, when all answers are available I call a function in JS, which initiates to fetch all Date from the native code  :

```
this.webView.sendJavascript("fetchValues("+ mResultArrayForResultValues+");");
```

If someone has a better approach to solve this - please post it. So far I will use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like AsyncTasks better, but hey, however you get there =]

I also like Vito's answer (the one that isn't checked) on that page a lot more; that calls the javascript directly; it's how I've called javascripts anyway.

gl hf

Comment: sorry, did not get your point. I prefer to use the callback solution

Comment: yes, but it seems it's deprecated, or not working anymore ( I dunno; haven't checked. ) An async doesn't depend on the callback being called. Is there a reason beyond preference that asyncs won't work? Try it, you might like it =]

Comment: yeah, where do you got the information from, that the callback-solution is deprecated ? I will have a try - thanks a lot !

Comment: from you =] I'm only able to tell you what I know works, and seeing something like PluginAdapter just gives me shivers... AsyncTasks aren't going anywhere; they are also fantastically powerful; this is probably not applicable to your problem, but when you want to take information from the UI, do something time consuming, then change the UI, notify adapters, and create onClickListeners on that data there is nothing so handy as AsyncTasks; I hand them out at christmas, I listen to autoreaders of them while I brush my teeth... =] My advice is to call it with "new myAsyncTask(data).execute();"

Comment: Well I have another question : When I call the JS function and I return any PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT, as shown in the given link at the startpost, is the JS function finished after that ? Or does it wait until I send another PluginResult with PluginResult.Status.OK ?

Comment: Well, having done exactly no research on PluginResult further than reading that post, I'd say it should still be alive, else the answer would not have helped the OP.