# AngularJS, cordova, check connection on every request

Tags: angularjs, cordova, network-connection

I have an app that has many controllers and most of them are sending requests to the server. What I would like to do is to check if there is internet connection.

I do that using:

```
   if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
        alert("Oops! You are not connected to the internet!");
    }else{
        alert("Yes! You are connected to the internet!");
  };
```

Where in app.js and how should I make it to check if there is internet connection on every request made? I tried to add to `.config` just before my `authInterceptor` but I can't make it work.

Ps. It works only if I place it in a function inside a controller and call it.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751522/android-phonegap-notify-javascript-when-an-asynctask-is-finished/24534081#24534081.

Comment: To be honest this that question is more complicated. I'm looking for something really simple. The code above works, but the issue is that I don't know how to call the function on every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write an http interceptor. It's basically a special service you register that gets fired with every request. You can check if you have a connection in there and do what you will with that info. Here is a decent example of how to implement one

http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/

Comment: I saw this good article, thanks. But in a case of "request interceptor", it's easy for me to display a message like "you're not connected", but how do you prevent the HTTP request to be actually executed?

Comment: @DavidW. If you override the request and requestError functions you can prevent it. If you return a rejected promise from the request function, it will fire your requestError function. From there you can handle that rejection however you'd like.